# Edit XML File and Save it from PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to edit this XML file and update the values, and save to existing XML file.

```
<resources>
    <string name="application">generation</string>
    <string name="application2">generation2</string>
    <string-type name="type">single</string-type>
</resources>
```

I need to update the values, 'generation', 'generation2', 'single' from db.
Thanks... hope a quick response. Thanks again.

How to delete child nods??!

Comment: Where do you want to edit this XML? in your client side script using java script or on server side in PHP?

Comment: @HaBo server side in php

Comment: see if this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956601/change-xml-node-element-value-in-php-and-save-file?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) which can parse XML or HTML, modify it and export the modified version back to a string.

Comment: hi André Daniel how to delete a child node

Comment: @user2645118 `node.removeChild($child)`, as described here : http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php - there is also a nice example showing how to load an XML file and how to save the modified XML, that's similar to what you need.

Comment: That would be $node->removeChild($child)

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox i'm too used to Python lately... too bad i can't edit my comment. Thanks for correcting me though.